# How do I restart the function?

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to print random integers each time the button is clicked and the function is executed, however, I only get the same result, unless I restart the program.

Here's my code:

```
num1= randint(0,9)

testbtn_txt = tk.StringVar()
testbtn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=testbtn_txt, command=lambda:testfunc(), font="Arial", bg="#808080", fg="white", height=1, width=10)
testbtn_txt.set("Test")
testbtn.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5)

def testfunc():
    print(num1)
```

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the random number generation to the function. `randint` isn't magic - you'll have to call it again to get a new random number.

```
def testfunc():
    num1 = randint(0,9)
    print(num1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`num1` is initialized to a random value, but that value is kept for the duration of the program. Instead you could move the randomizing into the function itself:

```py
def testfunc():
    num1 = randint(0,9)
    print(num1)
```

Or even more concisely:

```py
def testfunc():
    print(randint(0,9))
```

Answer (score 1):

do this:

`def testfunc(): print(randint(0,9))`

or

`def getnum():  return randint(0,9)`
`def testfunc(): print(getnum())`